# How to translate timestamp?

Tags: translation

This script comes with the theme I purchased that output "Published 3 days ago on Feb 21, 2019" on the article. However I couldn't get the "%s ago" translated, which includes variables of minute(s), hour(s), day(s), etc. What is the best way to translate just these variables?

```
<?php esc_html_e( 'Published', 'enews' ); ?>
<?php printf(esc_html__( '%s ago', 'enews' ), human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );?> 
<?php esc_html_e( 'on', 'enews' ); ?><time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?>">
<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></time>
```

Comment: Which part is not translated? The "ago" word, or the human time diff part?

Comment: There is a example in codex which you can use - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff

Answer (score 0):

The `"%s"` will be replaced by strings translated in the WordPress Core "default" text domain. e.g. `"%s mins"`, `"%s hours"`, etc..

Find these in your core translation files and translate them too.